# find the salay according to the name in first map

Tags: java, collections

How to find the salary using a `value` obtained from a `Map` and using it as a `key` to find the **salary** in another `Map`.

Example get name from first map - `bryan` and show the `salary` from second map `20000`

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.HashSet;
  import java.util.Iterator;
  import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
  import java.util.Set;

  public class twomaps {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        LinkedHashMap <Integer, String> hmap = new  LinkedHashMap <Integer, String>();
        LinkedHashMap <String, String> hmap2 = new  LinkedHashMap <String, String>();
        hmap.put(22, "bryan");
        hmap.put(11,"Savi");

        hmap2.put("16000", "Savi");
        hmap2.put("20000", "bryan");

        // i know this part is not correct but was writing something is better than nothing
        boolean b = hmap.values().contains("bryan");
        if(b==true){
           if(hmap2.values().equals(hmap2))         
        }                   
    }      
  }
```

Comment: Just wondering why didn't you create a Employee object and put it in map ?

Comment: @ANS i can but is there any way to get what i want by this way..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using the below code, but the best way is, **create an `Employee` type and store the `employee` objects into the `map`, which will really make things more clear and object oriented**.

```
//check if both the maps contain the "bryan"
if(hmap.containsValue("bryan") && hmap2.containsValue("bryan")) {

     //iterate over the hmap2 using the keys
     for(String key : hmap2.keySet()) {

          //if the value is bryan, then get the key, which is the salary
          if(hmap2.get(key) != null && hmap2.get(key).equals("bryan")) {
              System.out.println(key);
          }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple one:

```
String name1 = "bryan";
hmap2.forEach((salary, name2) -> {
    if (name2.equals(name1)) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Salary for %s is %s", name1, salary));
    }
});
```